Importing JS module on client-side with SSR
I have my angular 18 application running with SSR.
I have the following import which fails on page load as the igv.js file contains client-side objects like window, etc:
import * as igv from 'igv';

I need to dynamically import the javascript file on the client-side so that it doesn't fail with the SSR.
I tried the code below but am getting the error message TypeError: igv.createBrowser is not a function,
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
  const promise = import("/Users/Projects/angular-project/igv.js");
  promise.then(igv=> {
    try {
      this.browser = igv.createBrowser(this.igvDiv.nativeElement, this.options);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

  });
}

Any idea how to dynamically load the igv module on client-side?

What happens is that ngAfterViewInit Lifecycle Hook: Ensures the dynamic import and createBrowser call happen after the view initialization to access the DOM element (this.igvDiv.nativeElement).
import { Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {

  browser: any;
  options: any = { /* your options here */ };

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      import('/Users/Projects/angular-project/igv.js').then(igvModule => {
        const igv = igvModule.default;
        if (igv && typeof igv.createBrowser === 'function') {
          this.browser = igv.createBrowser(this.igvDiv.nativeElement, this.options);
        } else {
          console.error('igv.createBrowser is not a function');
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error loading igv module:', error);
      });
    }
  }
}


I spent 2 days trying to find a solution for that!! I can't thank you enough for your answer

@Kim always no worries, happy to help, keep coding :)
